# How to pass client_id from AWS API Gateway request to the backend

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, aws-api-gateway

I have a python API server running in ECS, with access controlled through API Gateway, with requests then passed through a NLB and an ALB.  Authorization in API Gateway is handled with a Cognito user pool.  Everything is fully functional.

On the actual API server, I have functions that are tied to specific client_ids.  I was expecting to be able to parse the client_id from the request headers after authentication in API Gateway, but either they aren't being passed with the requests or I'm just missing how to actually retrieve it.  I can't seem to find any tutorials showing how to configure API Gateway to forward this information with the requests so I thought I'd ask here.  The API Server is a python-flask server autogenerated by the swagger editor from my OpenAPI 3.0 specification, if that matters.

Comment: Do these help?  https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/custom-headers-api-gateway-lambda/ or https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-method-settings-execution-console.html

Answer (score 0):

Update:

It turned out to already be passing the authorization token that I needed.
I can obtain header information for each request that hits my flask endpoint with the command `headers = connexion.request.headers`.  I then decode the token using this tool: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-support-tools/tree/master/Cognito/decode-verify-jwt